# Display the history of an object in two apps together in django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, history

I have two apps (profiling and ticketing) the ticketing app has three models in names of member,ticket,comment, and the profiling app has one model in name of  profile. I do some changes on an profile object via profiling app it displays on profile model history but if I change that object via "inline" from another model the history displays on that  model not profile model. I want that  history will be displays completly in two models.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used 'django-simple-history' and it solved my problem  ,
this was exactly what I needed: "https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin.html"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).